# Markdown failure in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, markdown, jquery-1.9, wmd-markdown

I'm using [this jQuery Markdown from *arhpreston*](https://github.com/arhpreston/jquery-markdown) for my purposes. My jQuery code(though irrelevant) is:

```
var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#content').html( converter.makeHtml($('#content').text()) );
});
```

Where, `#content` is a `div`:

```
<div id="content">This is another of most common type of error. It is usually encountered when you are trying something which needs a user registration(at the very least). If you haven't registered on the hub yet, **Gods help you!**.

Anyways, the hub is mostly open for registrations on weekends(*generally* Sunday; sometimes Saturday too). Keep looking at the **Hub Topic** for the notifying information on the registration details. 

### NOTE
You must not, under any non-dire circumstance ask any Admin to get your nick registered. We *WILL* be banning you. It is annoying if nothing else.</div>
```

Everything is working fine and I'm having no troubles at all. The only thing is the text is parsed as semi-HTML in Internet Explorer as shown in the screenshot:

[image: MS IE sucks, as usual]

<sub>MS IE sucks, as usual</sub>

As can be seen in the screenshot, all my strong and italics are being parsed with correct HTML but all other markups fail. The links (with `[1]:` scheme) get parsed, but not linked to the actual content. They are just appended at the end as text.

The following content between `hr` displays how it should be parsed instead.

---

This is another of most common type of error. It is usually encountered when you are trying something which needs a user registration(at the very least). If you haven't registered on the hub yet, **Gods help you!**.

Anyways, the hub is mostly open for registrations on weekends(*generally* Sunday; sometimes Saturday too). Keep looking at the **Hub Topic** for the notifying information on the registration details.

#### NOTE

You must not, under any non-dire circumstance ask any Admin to get your nick registered. We *WILL* be banning you. It is annoying if nothing else.

---

I am using IE 7 for this. But the problem is there on IE 8 as well. jQuery version is 1.9.1. The page has no problems in parsing on any other browser(Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) in any other OS(Windows Xp to 8, *nix and Leopard). I don't have any problem by showing IE users a message to use some other browser. **Just want to know where from is this fault originating?**

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but it could be something related to IE8 and under using [different javascript engines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/18/the-new-javascript-engine-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx). It seems _possible_ this is affecting the interpretation of the code in such a way that you are seeing the discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the call to `.text()` with a call to `.html()`.  I have not verified this, but do recall something to this effect with earlier versions of IE.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It didn't help though. The content is still being parsed partially.